# How do I stop matlab-prettifier thinking print strings are comments?

Tags: comments, strings, matlab, matlab-prettifier

I am trying to put my code into a Latex document using matlab-prettifier. I am doing this by using \lstinputlisting[style=Matlab-editor]{Trap.m}.

An example of Trap.m (a MATLAB file) is as follows

```
step size = 5
sub_int=100
fprintf("To get an estimation to two decimal places we needed a step size of %f which is %.0f intervals. \n",  step_size, sub_int)
```

When I run matlab-prettifier it assumes that after '%' the string is actually a comment and not a statement. As it is meant to be inputting a float into a string then the colour should be black. I am unsure how to correct this.

I have included a MWE below for Latex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
Text...
\lstinputlisting[style=Matlab-editor]{Trap.m}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, could you please post a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that we can work on?

Comment: I have uploaded a MWE.

Comment: MATLAB strings (and the first parameter of `fprint` is one) are delimited by single quotes, not by double quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use single quotes instead of double quotes to wrap the string

Or else you can define some escape character and put '%' inside the escape characters. Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\lstset{
escapechar         = `,
    }
\begin{document}
Text...
\lstinputlisting[style=Matlab-editor]{Trap.m}
\end{document}
```

Trap.m

```
step size = 5
sub_int=100
fprintf('To get an estimation to two decimal places we needed a step size of %f which is %.0f intervals. \n',  step_size, sub_int)
fprintf("To get an estimation to two decimal places we needed a step size of `\%`f which is `\%`.0f intervals. \n",  step_size, sub_int)
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
\lstset{style=Matlab-editor}
\lstset{morestring=[m]"}

\lstinputlisting{filename.m}
```

It really ought to be added to the style file, perhaps with a version option so that buggy pre-2017 code is still highlighted "correctly", but CTAN doesn't list a repository so I can't just send a pull request.